# How to call object methods for an object in an array using a foreach loop

Tags: php, oop, foreach

I am trying to store a collection of objects and can't call object methods in a foreach loop. This is basically what I have. The print function prints nothing. Is there something I am over looking or is this not the way to go about it?

```
class person
{
    private $name;

    public function __construct($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function get_name() {
        return $this->name;
    }
}

$test_set[] = new person("John");
$test_set[] = new person("Jane");

foreach($test_set as $set_item) {
    print $set_item->get_name();
}
```

Comment: I copy-pasted your code and it works fine. The problem is somewhere else. Do you have error reporting turned on?

Comment: This is a simplified version of my code. I copy pasted it, and it worked too. It must be something in my more advanced class.

Comment: Try this code. It might be the multiple parameter construct? https://gist.github.com/a7e525e84cb95057a676

Comment: Another typo, it's called `__construct()`...

Answer (score 4):

You need to set your name like this (probably just a typo):

```
public function __construct($name) {
    $this->name = $name; // not $this->$name
}
```

Comment: That was a typo on here. It still does not change the blank output.

Comment: Well for me it works in a test file. Any error output with `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');` at the top?

Comment: @DanLee I did set both of those, and everything is good. It is just printing nothing.

Comment: Try it with `echo` then? I can't explain this behaviour. Or you need to give us more of the code.

Answer (score 2):

Your loop is working. But your class contains a mistake.

Replace:

```
    public function __construct($name) {
        $this->$name = $name;
    }
```

With:

```
    public function __construct($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
```

Comment: Ugh @ anonymous down-votes. Maybe because the downvoter thought it came several minutes later than a very similar answer. But is still correct.